# How to see results (equation) of a Regression in Python?

Tags: python, regression

I would like to see the regression equation for a polynomial regression in python.

I am new to python, in R the analogous command I am looking for is "summary." I have tried the print function in python.

```
x = (LIST)
y = (LIST)

x = x[:, np.newaxis]
y = y[:, np.newaxis]

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)

poly.fit(x_poly,y)
lin = LinearRegression()
lin.fit(x_poly,y)
y_poly_pred = lin.predict(x_poly)

print(lin)
print(poly)
print(lin.predict)
print(poly.fit_transform)
```

I would like the output to give me the ax^2 + bx + c equation, or at least the info to figure out that equation. Instead, I get (below) for my 4 print statements.

```
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, 
normalize=False)
PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=True, interaction_only=False,
               order='C')
<bound method LinearModel.predict of LinearRegression(copy_X=True, 
fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False)>
<bound method TransformerMixin.fit_transform of 
PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=True, interaction_only=False,
               order='C')>
```

Comment: for the lin: 
slope, intercept= model.coef_[0][0], model.intercept_[0] ?

Comment: @David8, I got "(0.0, 0.2456191379139704)" back for that, I will assume 2.5 is the y-intercept. This is helpful, but what about the "poly.fit_transform?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example graphical polynomial fitter using numpy.polyfit for fitting and numpy.polyval for evaluation. This example has eight data points, and making polynomialOrder = 7 shows Runge's phenomenon rather nicely.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7, 0.0])
yData = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7, 0.1])

polynomialOrder = 2 # example quadratic

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, polynomialOrder)
print('Fitted Parameters:', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xData)
absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```